# how to create a signed tag with pygit2 API

Tags: python, git, gnupg, gpg-signature, pygit2

I am an experienced Python developer, but not quite familiar with `pygit2` and git related stuff.

Recently, I need to implement some functionality for operations on git repository.

One of it is to create a signed tag with `pygit2` and `python-gnupg`.

https://www.pygit2.org/

https://gnupg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

I can successfully create signed commit and there is a lot of documents and posts related to signed commit via `pygit2`. But for signed tag, it seems that its format is slightly different from signed commit. And there is no document about it.

I have read https://git-scm.com/docs/signature-format. It seems that signature on git tag is appending to it.

I have found this https://github.com/libgit2/pygit2/issues/1276. It is asked by someone else before me. But not get response yet.

Can anyone tell me how git signed tag works in low level and show me some sample code?